# Unusual kubernetes usage

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to create a service with kubernetes which allows reading files with filebeat.

So, I have kubernetes cluster and I would create Deployment/Statefulset or any other to manage pods.

Next, I have many folders with log files.

I would set a single folder with files to a single pod. So, in result it must be "folders count"=="pods count". I know that this is not a normal job for k8s, but I guess this is possible somehow.

The first way I found is to generate ConfigMap with settings for each Pod, but it's not exactly what I need as it's too hard to manage each pod as standalone service, I cannot stop selecting POD for maintenance, for an example.

Comment: Where should be the folders? In the pods, in the nodes, in you local machine?

Comment: @suren I can mount the main folder to every pod. So, the mount is not a problem, a folder with subfolders is accessible for each pod

Comment: What's exactly your questions then?

Comment: @suren Question is, k8s is designed to replicate the same pods. So, I don't know a valid way to give to each pod individual config (with the unique folder). Well, actually I can, but I should then generate YAML file to create Deployment/DaemonSet/Statefulset and this is the wrong way because I cannot then manage each pod as standalone service. I have to stop the whole SET of pods to get off one. I would like create some set which allows managing pods individually, so I can stop one of them without stopping all others.

Comment: Yeah, that's an unusual one. I wonder why isn't is possible to start a completed stopped/completed pod; like with docker.

Comment: @suren yep, it's much easy with docker swarm for an example, with docker itself too, but I guess not with k8s

Comment: [Estatic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515354/estatic) You can achieve this by creating independent deployment  for each folder and manage it, also you can just create a lot YAMLs with a pod and develop custom controller for manage that.